# Reply to All on Latest Sent Email Using Partial Subject Name

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, outlook

I send reports with Subject Name Like "Sales Report till 01-Sep-2022" in which only the date changes and initial like "Sales Report till*" remains the same.

Below is the code for "Replying to All" from sent items, which works well on "Replying to All" from sent items. The only problem is it's not replying on latest Sent Email.

It picks any email with "Sales Report till" whether that sent mail is from last week or last month.

I want to Reply to All on the latest Sent Email.

```vb
Sub OL_Email_Reply_To_All_WFN()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim objMail As Object
Dim objReplyToThisMail As MailItem
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim objConversation As Conversation
Dim objTable As Table
Dim objVar As Variant

Dim Path, WFN, SN As String
Dim WFN_Sub, WFN_RN, WFN_MB As String

Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Sheet").Range("B1") & "\"    '''''Path to pick from "Main_Sheet" of ThisWorkbook
WFN = Path & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Sheet").Range("B2")   ''''' Working File Name can be diffrent will change on sheet.
  
''''WFN_Sub = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Sheet").Range("B3")
''''WFN_RN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Sheet").Range("B4")
''''WFN_MB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Sheet").Range("B5")
''''WFN_SN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Sheet").Range("B6")


'''''Original Subject Name looks like "Sales Report till 01-Sep-2022" in which date changes every everytime.

WFN_Sub = "Test Email"   '''''Subject to find should be intial only
WFN_RN = "Hi Friend"     '''''Recipient Name
WFN_MB = "Please ignore it's a Test Email"    ''''''''''Mail Body
    SN = "My Name"   '''''''''Senders Name

Set olApp = Session.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

lngCount = 1

ThisWorkbook.Activate
For Each objMail In Fldr.Items
    If TypeName(objMail) = "MailItem" Then
        If InStr(objMail.Subject, WFN_Sub) <> 0 Then

            Set objConversation = objMail.GetConversation
            Set objTable = objConversation.GetTable
            objVar = objTable.GetArray(objTable.GetRowCount)
            Set objReplyToThisMail = olApp.Session.GetItemFromID(objVar(UBound(objVar), 0))

            With objReplyToThisMail.ReplyAll
                .Subject = WFN_Sub & " " & Format(Now() - 1, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
                .HTMLBody = WFN_RN & "<br> <br>" & WFN_MB & "<br> <br>" & "Kind Regards" & "<br>" & SN
                .display
                .Attachments.Add WFN
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    End If

Next objMail
Set olApp = Nothing
Set olNs = Nothing
Set Fldr = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set objReplyToThisMail = Nothing
lngCount = Empty
Set objConversation = Nothing
Set objTable = Nothing
If IsArray(objVar) Then Erase objVar

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Before getting the last row in the table (retrieved from the conversation object) you need to [sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.table.sort) items based on the recieved date:

```
 'Sort by ReceivedTime in descending order 
 table.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
```

Only after that you may rely on the last item in the code.

Comment: Hi Eugene, Thanks Buddy. But still I am not getting the desired result. Could you be more detailed as I am not much comfortable with Excel-VBA if used for Outlook.

Comment: What code do you have now with the Sort method involved?

Comment: `Set objConversation = objMail.GetConversation
Set objTable = objConversation.GetTable

objTable.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
Set Items = Fldr.Items

Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True


objVar = objTable.GetArray(objTable.GetRowCount)
Set objReplyToThisMail = olApp.Session.GetItemFromID(objVar(UBound(objVar), 0))`

Comment: Have you tried to print the received dates of all entries in the collection? Do you get the last one?

Comment: I am getting the first one. eg 01-Sep every time. I am trying to get closest date of present date.

Comment: @PritamSingh [Table.Sort method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.table.sort) `objTable.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"` same as `objTable.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False`.

Answer (score 0):

There is possibly simpler code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub OL_Email_Reply_To_All_WFN()

' reference Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFldr As Outlook.Folder

Dim objMail As Object

Dim Path As String, WFN As String, SN As String
Dim WFN_Sub As String, WFN_RN As String, WFN_MB As String

'Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Sheet").Range("B1") & "\"    '''''Path to pick from "Main_Sheet" of ThisWorkbook
'WFN = Path & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Sheet").Range("B2")   ''''' Working File Name can be diffrent will change on sheet.
  
''''WFN_Sub = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Sheet").Range("B3")
''''WFN_RN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Sheet").Range("B4")
''''WFN_MB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Sheet").Range("B5")
''''WFN_SN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main_Sheet").Range("B6")


'''''Original Subject Name looks like "Sales Report till 01-Sep-2022" in which date changes every everytime.

WFN_Sub = "Test Email"   '''''Subject to find should be intial only
WFN_RN = "Hi Friend"     '''''Recipient Name
WFN_MB = "Please ignore it's a Test Email"    ''''''''''Mail Body
    SN = "My Name"   '''''''''Senders Name

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

Dim fldrItems As Outlook.Items
Set fldrItems = olFldr.Items
fldrItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To fldrItems.Count

    If TypeName(fldrItems(i)) = "MailItem" Then
        If InStr(fldrItems(i).Subject, WFN_Sub) <> 0 Then
        
            Debug.Print fldrItems(i).ReceivedTime
            
            With fldrItems(i).ReplyAll
                .Subject = WFN_Sub & " " & Format(Now() - 1, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
                .htmlbody = WFN_RN & "<br> <br>" & WFN_MB & "<br> <br>" & "Kind Regards" & "<br>" & SN
                .Display
                '.Attachments.Add WFN
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    End If

Next

Set olApp = Nothing
Set olNs = Nothing
Set olFldr = Nothing
Set fldrItems = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing

End Sub
```